# How to deal with output from a background linux task

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, background-process

I have a task that is continuously echoing info.

For example, if you do a git clone and you want to send that task to the background (by using ampersand)

```
git clone https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js.git &
```

then the git clone operation is constantly refreshing the screen with the new percentage of the git clone process, ie:

```
Receiving objects:  47% (22332/47018), 92.53 MiB | 480 KiB/s   1410/47018), 7.18 MiB | 185 KiB/s
Receiving objects:  53% (24937/47018), 99.40 MiB | 425 KiB/s   1410/47018), 7.18 MiB | 185 KiB/s
```

So I cannot continue doing other operations in the foreground, as these updates are preventing me to see what I am trying to write.

Can you tell me guys how to effectively send one verbose task like this to the background?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could have the process write its output to a file (if you need to view it later) like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js.git >output.txt &
```

or discard the output altogether like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js.git >/dev/null &
```

edit:

you could also include any error messages sent to stderror in either of the above options by replacing the `&` with `2>&1 &`

Comment: many thanks for your answer! This is exactly what I was looking for. How beautiful this command is!

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are good, but you can also use:

```
git clone -q ...
```

[See here for details](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html).

Comment: this is a great option if git is the only command you want to hide in the background like this.  +1 for that, but it's worth noting that the redirection is useful for any command, not just git.

Comment: Of course, redirection is most generic. But I personally don't like redirection just to discard output. Almost all (reasonable) commands that have a progress indicator like this one have a "quiet" option.

Comment: fair point.  just throwing that out there for anyone reading along with us.

Comment: great idea, thanks a lot! I accept the other answer because that one was more relevant to the question I made. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1):

redirect its standard output:

```
git clone https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js.git > /dev/null &
```

or use appropriate verbose options of the command (in this case git)

Answer (score -1):

If you are specifically looking to put it in the background you can append an ampersand (`&`) to the end of the command, or while it is running use `ctrl+z` then the command `'bg'` to run it in the background.
To bring it back, use `jobs` to list your jobs and then `fg %{job #}` to bring it back.
Hope this helps and works in this unique situation

Comment: He's already got the job in the background. He wants it to stop sending output to the terminal where he's doing other stuff in the foreground.

Comment: my misunderstanding. Redirection of all the output does sound ideal then. :\